# Problem starting tomcat (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Tags: tomcat, amazon-linux

I have an amazon linux machine and I am configuring
it to run an app, I made it through an AMI and deleted the old user, when I try to use the command "sudo systemctl start tomcat" I am getting the error (code=exited, status=217/USER), any idea what it could to be?

systemctl status tomcat.service

```
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-12-19 09:56:59 -03; 10s ago
  Process: 3307 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/test/scripts/start-tomcats.sh (code=exited, status=217/USER)
```

my tomcat.service
`[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/test/scripts/start-tomcats.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/test/scripts/shutdown-tomcats.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I created a new user and redid all the work thinking it would fix it but the problem persisted

Comment: I managed to solve it, in case anyone is having the same problem. To resolve, enter the correct name in the 'User=  Group='